# Failed to get item from dynamoDB using GetItemCommand (JS)

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I am new to dynamoDB and trying to perform some basic operations to learn the subject.
I have successfully created a table using AWS SDK (so no credentials issue) like this:

```js
const newTable = async () => {
  //* it's working!!!
  try {
    const params = {
      AttributeDefinitions: [
        {
          AttributeName: 'email',
          AttributeType: 'S',
        },
        {
          AttributeName: 'password',
          AttributeType: 'S',
        },
      ],
      KeySchema: [
        {
          AttributeName: 'email',
          KeyType: 'HASH',
        },
        {
          AttributeName: 'password',
          KeyType: 'RANGE',
        },
      ],
      ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5,
      },
      TableName,
      StreamSpecification: {
        StreamEnabled: false,
      },
    };
    const command = new CreateTableCommand(params);
    const data = await client.send(command);
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

I inserted a new item into the table using the AWS console, and now I'm trying to access it using the SDK as follows:

```js
const getItem = async () => {
  try {
    const params = {
      TableName,
      Key: {
        email: { S: 'ofer@email.com' },
      },
    };
    const command = new GetItemCommand(params);
    const response = await client.send(command);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

When I try to run the code, the following error is received: *"ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema"*

I couldn't figure out where my mistake was

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a composite key, both HASH and RANGE keys need to be specified when getting an item. Both `email` and `password` in your case.

> For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For
> example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value
> for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide
> values for both the partition key and the sort key.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#DDB-GetItem-request-Key

---

As a side note, you are unlikely to want to make a password a RANGE key.